# Is it bad design to call a controller method from a job class

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

I recently wanted to implement queue functionality to my Laravel project, and as of now, it works. However, I'm not sure what the proper design pattern for a solution like this is since I'm new to Laravel.

I have a sync() method inside a ProductController class which is a void method that calls to an API, gets products, and inserts/updates records in a database. Since it takes around 2-5 minutes for the function to execute, I decided to try and implement a job to do it in the background.

I wasn't sure whether to copy the whole method and paste it into the handle() method inside the "SyncProducts" job class or call it from the controller class.

As of now, my job class looks like this.

```
class SyncProducts implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public $timeout = 1800;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        try {
            (new \App\Http\Controllers\ProductController)->sync();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
        } catch (ResourceException $e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the ProductController class, I added a new method that dispatches the job and redirects the user.

```
public function syncRun()
{
    SyncProducts::dispatch();

    return back();
}
```

Is this bad design? What is the proper way to implement it?

Comment: You're calling `sync()` but are showing us a method called `syncRun()`? How are they related? A better design would be to move the logic out from the controller into a service. Then you can call the same service from both your job and from your controller.

Comment: sync() method is the long, executable method inside the ProductController, syncRun() is the method which the route currently calls so the job is dispatched and run in the background, naming is probably not ideal.

Comment: Okay so if I understand correctly then in situations like this one, the logic that would normally be in a Controller, goes to the handle method inside the job class?

Comment: Normally, a controller doesn't contain any business logic. A controller only takes the request, calls the correct service that handles the business logic and then returns the result. If you have the business logic in a service, you can call that service from where ever you want/need without needing to go through the controller.

Comment: If you only need to run the code from a job then leave it as it is. If you need to run the same logic from http request, or a command, or a queued job, then move the logic into an Action class.  As to your question, it is miss worded. You are dispatching a job from a controller, which is fine.  Your question title is not fine (calling controller from a job). Don't do this.  Controllers are for handling Http requests.

Comment: why not just call `SyncProducts::dispatch();` from the job?

Comment: @Solpadeine understood your issue. Do not call the controller's method from your job class. It's bad practice. You just need to copy your logic and paste it to the job's handle method and dispatch the job from sync() which is in the respective controller. Remember you can pass the request object or any custom params at the time of dispatch and it is available in the job's constructor. Just read this [Jobs and Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#class-structure) of laravel. It is very easy to implement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I consider it as bad design, and instead would use an action class which holds the logic in a re-usable way. The action class then can be called from a controller or from a job.

Here a (fairly basic) overview, for the sole purpose of giving an idea about the concept:

```php
class MyWhateverAction
{
    public function __construct($data) {
        // whatever you need
    }

   
    public function execute()
    {
       // the logic which you now have in the controller
    }
}
```

```php
class MyWhateverController
{
    public function synch($request, MyWhateverAction $action)
    {
       // do something to set $data

       $action->execute($data)

       return // whatever you need
    }
}
```

```php
class MyWhateverJob
{
    public function handle($data, MyWhateverAction $action)
    {
       $action->execute($data)
    }
}
```

More detailed infos about it:
a) https://stitcher.io/blog/laravel-queueable-actions
b) https://twitter.com/mmartin_joo/status/1509181862014509065?s=21